# How can I read text from a specific window?

Tags: python, minecraft

I have the chatlog window of my minecraft game open, and I want to get every message in the chatlog. Also please dont suggest something like pyTesseract because I want the program to run while I'm playing the game.

Here's a screenshot of the log if it will help anyway
[image]

Comment: https://hypixel.net/threads/guide-viewing-minecraft-chat-logs.92416/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just parse the latest logfile ... i dont know why you would be trying to parse some window thing ...

something like

```
import os
fpath = os.path.expandvars(r"%appdata%\.minecraft\logs\latest.log")
with open(fpath) as f:
    f.seek(-1) # jump to end
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:# no new text
           # might want to add a bit of a sleep 
           continue 
        print("Log Line:",line)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed, I didnt know it existed sorry about that

Comment: Hey one more question, this process is way too slow, is there a faster method? because the chat lines are on the bottom and the program has to go through all useless lines before it

Comment: you can use `f.seek(-1)` to jump to the end of the file before you start looping over the new lines coming in

Comment: as an aside i suspect minecraft buffers the logs so it might not be in "realtime"